# Fancybox The requested content cannot be loaded

Tags: fancybox

I'm using fancybox plugin for my image gallery and having really interested trouble.
I have image gallery groups.
On my first group, if i click hover link for to open first image. i'm getting an error like "The requested content cannot be loaded.
Please try again later."
But it works fine in other image groups. For example please check http://www.naplesoft.com/hotels/likya-residence-and-spa-and-the-likya-retreat/?tab=rooms

Click view more info for Deluxe room, then click hover link "Click here to view more room images"
You will get an error.

But if you go other room types like "Deluxe room 106 or other ones" it works fine.
I don't know what did i wrong?

Here is PHP

```
           <?php if (count($room['room_images']) > 0 ) { ?>  
        <p><a class="fancybox" rel="gallery<?php echo $counter; ?>" href="<?php echo $image['image']['sizes']['large']; ?>" title="<?php echo $image['caption']; ?>" >Click here</a> to view more room images</p>
        <div class="image">
          <?php // $isFirst = true;
                            foreach ($room['room_images'] as $image ) {
                                // if (!$isFirst) { ?>
          <div class="foto"> <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery<?php echo $counter; ?>" href="<?php echo $image['image']['sizes']['large']; ?>" title="<?php echo $image['caption']; ?>" ><img style="width:150px; height:96px;" src="<?php echo $image['image']['sizes']['thumbnail']; ?>" alt="" /></a> </div>
```

Any helps?